# python nmap module could not be found

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nmap

Python version and pip list are shown below

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64>python --version
Python 3.6.6

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64>pip list
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Package     Version
----------- -------
pip         19.1.1
python-nmap 0.6.1
setuptools  28.8.0
```

However, when I try to import nmap module in the code, I see following.

```
No module named 'nmap'
Stack trace:
 >  File "C:\Users\root\source\repos\PythonApplication3\PythonApplication3\PythonApplication3.py", line 1, in <module>
 >    import nmap
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**
I have pip3 installed as well. Below is its output showing nmap module is present.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64>pip3 list
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
pip (9.0.3)
python-nmap (0.6.1)
setuptools (39.0.1)
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 19.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: I am not using Windows, but it seems that pip should be pip3? As you can also see a warning about python2.7. Can you try pip3 list. Might just need to install the package for python v3.

Comment: @NicLaforge I updated my question with pip3 output

Comment: Are you running your code from VSCode? Or command line? As your interpreter in VScode might not point to the right one. If so can you try to run your code from command line. It would be: ```python C:\Users\root\source\repos\PythonApplication3\PythonApplication3\PythonApplication3.py```

Comment: I was running from Visual Studio. Running from the command line also report the same error. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nmap'

Comment: Can you try to add it to your local user. ```pip3 install --user python-nmap```

Comment: Doing that reports "Requirement already satisfied: python-nmap in c:\users\root\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages"

Comment: ```pip3 uninstall python-nmap```, then ```pip3 install --user python-nmap```

Comment: Now running my program reports  'nmap program was not found in path'

Comment: From the import or during a specific call?

Comment: Not from import. Its from the following line of code that is after import
nm_scan = nmap.PortScanner();

Comment: Seems that we fixed your first issue. There are thread about this issue, you can have a look at this post: https://bitbucket.org/xael/python-nmap/issues/19/nmap-program-was-not-found-in-path

Comment: ok. Can you add your comment as an answer, so I can mark it so. Thanks a lot for your help though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to uninstall it from the global location and install it to your user environment.

First uninstall the pacakge using:

```
pip3 uninstall python-nmap
```

Then re-install it using --user flag:

```
pip3 install --user python-namp
```

For your issue related to `nmap program was not found in path`

You may want to check this thread: [Not found in path while calling PortScanner](https://nmap.org/download.html)

Also python-nmap does not install the GUI version which might be in cause here. Find the install at: [Install nmap link](https://nmap.org/download.html)